# Line break gets replaced with rn in php

Tags: php, html, sql

So, I have a taxtarea where the user makes a blog post but when the user submits it their line breaks get replaced with a 'rn' and I don't know why. I thought it was the php script but when I rewrote it and after taking away the str_replaces' it still replaced a new line with a rn.

What is happening?

Comment: Post your codes, your structures, your tries...

Comment: Not only codes, but possible error. Its important to say what you expect from that. Telling us why your program not working is liable to close your question. Please, improve it with those information.

Comment: @bcesars I haven't gotten any errors but in 30ins I'll add my code attempts.

Comment: I'm having this problem, too. I can't offer much help, but I'll be keeping an eye on this question to see if any answers can help me.

Comment: See my answer. I was able to fix this for my own case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any stripslahes(). Stripslashes removes any backslashes and forward slashes. For example, line breaks are being sent as \n or \r and the stripslashes() takes away the backslashes in those, so that's why it says 'rn'.

I had this very problem, and this solution helped me. Good luck!

Comment: I already figured this problem out but thanx for the answer because it is exactly how I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

In textarea just like any Text Editor, New Line are carriage (\r) or newline feed (\n) characters or combination of the two (depending on the OS). To convert these characters to linebreak of HTML, use the *nl2br()* of PHP.

Check PHP Manual for reference.

Comment: I have tried that. It worked the first time but it somehow broke itself. I'm on my phone so I can't add the code attempts but I'll be at my computer in about 30 minutes. I'll add my code then

Comment: @hardeshorler Your answer helped me realise what the problem is. Thanx, I got it fixed.